# End to End SSL connection using Haproxy?

Tags: tomcat, ssl-certificate, https, haproxy, stunnel

I want to know about how Haproxy reacts when I want to make the HTTPS connection over the server. In apache we have aj_proxy to make a ssl connection to tomcat server, so how that functionality can be maintained using stunnel. We are using Haproxy v1.4.13. Our scenario is we want to put the certificates in stunnel and maintain HTTPS session.We are just using plain HTTP at backend. So, when I access the https://www.domain.com/login browser validate the certificate but after I login, then it is HTTP again, as it get the content from plain HTTP tomcat servers.

So is there any way that I can make the connection as HTTPS all the time. 
Below is the config file of stunnel :

```
sslVersion = all
options = NO_SSLv2
;Debug
debug = 7
output = /usr/local/etc/stunnel/stunnel.log
chroot = /var/tmp/stunnel

setuid = nobody
setgid = nobody
pid = /stunnel.pid

cert = /usr/local/etc/stunnel/stunnel.pem
;Some Performance Tunings

socket = l:TCP_NODELAY=1
socket = r:TCP_NODELAY=1
[https]
client = noaccept = 10.12.12.1:443
connect = 10.12.12.1:84
xforwardedfor=yes
TIMEOUTclose = 0
```

And Haproxy HTTPS frontend config:

```
.
.
.
listen https 10.12.12.1:84
    mode http
cookie JSESSIONID prefix
balance roundrobin
option forwardfor except 10.12.12.1
option httpclose
option http-server-close
server S1   10.12.12.2:8080 cookie server1  maxconn 5000    check
server S2   10.12.12.3:8080 cookie server2  maxconn 5000    check
.
.
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution by stunnel itself. I added RemoteIpValue class in tomcat server.xml configuration. Where I mentioned internalProxies as follow:

> ...  internalProxies="list of IP address of loadbalancers" ...

In my case:

```
internalProxies="10\.12\.12\.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using `nginx` as a frontend/reverse proxy instead of `stunnel` and redirect all traffic from http to https.

I'm not sure if `stunnel` can handle the http redirects.

Comment: Thanks. Initially I thought of using nginx but someway messed around with stunnel. Will check it and come back again

Comment: But is it possible that I use nginx infront of Haproxy, as I would like to proxy http request via haproxy ?

Comment: I didn't try nginx, but I tried pound and got the same problem. Since it is only decrypting the SSL and proxying the plain HTTP request to HAproxy.
I also tried to make stunnel to run in client and server mode. So that in server mode it do decryption and in client mode encrypted response to be sent to user. Since both client and server stunnel instances were in same machine, I was having problem in binding the port 8080 to accept in client mode.
Any body can help me  over this isse?